# Same Class Object With Different Methods For iOS and watchOS (Objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, apple-watch, nscoding, watchos

I am currently working on an iOS app that includes a `watchOS` app extension. In my iOS app I've made an `NSObject` subclass, which makes use of some objects from the `AVFoundation` framework in some of its methods.

On the Watch Extension side, I'm creating an `NSDictionary` object and then sending it to my iOS counterpart using the `WatchConnectivity` framework. I then use the `dictionary` to initialize my custom class.

I would like to be able to add my Watch Extension as one of the Targets for my custom class's `.m` file so that I can go ahead and create objects of my custom class on the watch and then send it over. (My class conforms to the `NSCoding` protocol so I can use `NSKeyArchiver` to represent my object using `NSData`, add it to a dictionary, then transferring that dictionary to the iOS device).

The Problem: `AVFoundation` is not available in `watchOS`, which my class utilizes. So is there a way to "omit" certain methods of a class depending which OS it's in.

Ex: In iOS, `UIImage` has the method `initWithCIImage:` but it is not available in `watchOS` since the `CoreImage` framework is not available.

(Perhaps I should recreate the class specifically for `watchOS` with all the same instance variables and use the same keys for the classes in the `NSCoding` methods, omitting `AVFoundation` from the `watchOS` version?)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can build your class using the macros available in `TargetConditionals.h`, for example `TARGET_OS_IOS` or `TARGET_OS_WATCH`, e.g.:

```
@implementation Foo

#ifdef TARGET_OS_IOS

- (void) someMethodThatUsesAVFoundation {
    // ...
}

#endif

@end
```

You'll also need to wrap `#include` directives to make sure you only include framework headers on the OS that actually supplies them.

Comment: I've wrapped all the methods in question as you've suggested, but I'm still getting build errors in those methods that use AVFoundation objects. Ex: "Use of undeclared identifier 'XXX'".

Comment: Without seeing all of your code I can't be more specific. This is the right technique to use for including (or not) code when you're building for a particular operating system. You'll have to look carefully through your code and make sure everything is setup correctly.